# Why use pandas.assign rather than simply initialize new column?

Tags: python, pandas

I just discovered the `assign` method for pandas dataframes, and it looks nice and very similar to dplyr's `mutate` in R. However, I've always gotten by by just initializing a new column 'on the fly'. Is there a reason why `assign` is better?

For instance (based on the example in the pandas documentation), to create a new column in a dataframe, I could just do this:

```
df = DataFrame({'A': range(1, 11), 'B': np.random.randn(10)})
df['ln_A'] = np.log(df['A'])
```

but the `pandas.DataFrame.assign` documentation recommends doing this:

```
df.assign(ln_A = lambda x: np.log(x.A))
# or 
newcol = np.log(df['A'])
df.assign(ln_A=newcol)
```

Both methods return the same dataframe. In fact, the first method (my 'on the fly' assignment) is significantly faster (0.202 seconds for 1000 iterations) than the `.assign` method (0.353 seconds for 1000 iterations).

So is there a reason I should stop using my old method in favour of `df.assign`?

Comment: I think it's matter of style

Comment: Well the only reason I know is that it allows method chaining. You can do things like `df.assign(some_col=some_exp).some_other_method_involving_the_new_column()`

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9229) also supports that it is mainly there for method chaining.

Comment: They are semantically different.  One is an in-place modification and the other is not.

Comment: The old version, ```df['ln_A'] = np.log(df['A'])```, may now raise a ```SettingWithCopyWarning```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The difference concerns whether you wish to *modify* an existing frame, or *create a new frame* while maintaining the original frame as it was.

In particular, `DataFrame.assign` returns you a *new* object that has a copy of the original data with the requested changes ... the original frame *remains unchanged*.

In your particular case:

```
>>> df = DataFrame({'A': range(1, 11), 'B': np.random.randn(10)})
```

Now suppose you wish to create a new frame in which `A` is everywhere `1` without destroying `df`.  Then you could use `.assign`

```
>>> new_df = df.assign(A=1)
```

If you do not wish to maintain the original values, then clearly `df["A"] = 1` will be more appropriate.  This also explains the speed difference, by necessity `.assign` must copy the data while `[...]` does not.

Answer (score 8):

The premise on [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) is that it returns:

> A new DataFrame with the new columns in addition to all the existing columns.

And also you cannot do anything in-place to change the original dataframe.

> The callable must not change input DataFrame (though pandas doesn't check it).

On the other hand `df['ln_A'] = np.log(df['A'])` will do things inplace.

---

> So is there a reason I should stop using my old method in favour of `df.assign`?

I think you can try `df.assign` but if you do **memory intensive stuff**, better to work what you did before or operations with `inplace=True`.