# Categorize age into another column age group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have this dataset

```
age
24
32
29
23
23
31
25
26
34
```

I want to categorize using python and save the result to a new column "agegroup" such that 
age between;
 23 to 26 to return 1 in the agegroup column, 
 27-30 to return value 2 in the agegroup column 
 and 31-34 to return 3 in the agegroup column

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html).

Given:

```
>>> df
   age
0   24
1   32
2   29
3   23
4   23
5   31
6   25
7   26
8   34
```

Solution:

```
>>> df.assign(agegroup=pd.cut(df['age'], bins=[23, 27, 31, 35], right=False, labels=[1, 2, 3]))
   age agegroup
0   24        1
1   32        3
2   29        2
3   23        1
4   23        1
5   31        3
6   25        1
7   26        1
8   34        3
```

Comment: what's the value of `df.assign(agegroup=` over just `df['agegroup']=`

Comment: @DavidErickson `df.assign(agegroup=...)` gives new df but `df['agegroup']` mutates the original df inplace.

Comment: @DavidErickson The former returns a new df and can be chained, the latter works in-place.

Comment: Thank you! I just read this quickly as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177914/why-use-pandas-assign-rather-than-simply-initialize-new-column I will start using df.assign

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionaries to do this as well. Key-value pairs. The keys would be the different age ranges and the value for a particular key would be the count for that particular age group.

groupDict={'23-26':0,'27-30':0,'31-34':0}

```
for i in ages:
 if i>=23 and i<=26:
   groupDict['23-26']+=1
 elif i>=27 and i<=30:
   groupDict['27-30']+=1
 elif i>=31 and i<=34:
   groupDict['27-30']+=1
```