# How to convert dictionary to dataframe and explode

Tags: python, pandas

I have list of dictionary

- I need to convert into dataframe
- Need to apply explode on all columns
- some element are one string
- some element are string separated by commas which has to split and explode

```
[
    {"var1": "EEA", "var2": "%K12%"},
    {"var1": "OVERALL"},
    {"var1": "ETLA"},
    {"var1": "A,B,C,D,E"},
    {"var1": "M,Q"},
    {"var1": "G,H"},
    {"var1": "I,J"},
    {"var1": "K,L,M"},
    {"var3": "R,T", "var2": "F"},
    {"var3": "EDUCATION", "var4": "TM"},
    {"var3": "A,B", "var4": "TM", "var5": "CCE,CCT,PP"},
    {"var1": "PHLT,PPSK,PLES,LPES", "var4": "HI"},
    {"var3": "EDUCATION", "var4": "HI", "var5": "CCM"},
    {"var3": "EDUCATION", "var4": "HI", "var5": "PP"},
    {"var4": "HI", "var5": "CCM"},
    {"var4": "HI", "var5": "PP"},
    {"var3": "A,B", "var6": "C"},
    {"var3": "", "var1": "", "var4": "", "var2": "", "var5": "", "var6": ""},
]
```

Comment: Please share your expected output.

Comment: Also, what you wish to explode? I cant see any lists?

Comment: @MehulGupta, the whole thing is inside a list. Are you asking if the values are resulting in a list to explode?

Comment: @MehulGupta once you convert to dataframe, both column some of values will be having comma separated values, which we need to explode

Comment: have you tried `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)` assuming the list is named `d = [ {'var1:'..},{....}]`

Comment: @JoeFerndz after converting to Dataframe  both column some of values will be having comma separated values, which we need to explode

Comment: @JoeFerndz yes, i tried after converting to dataframe i need to explode with comma seperated values

Comment: It can get a bit messy when we explode as `var1`, `var3`, and `var5` can explode as they have commas. What do you expect the desired result. That will help determine how the explode would end up.

Comment: @JoeFerndz yes i need to explode all the columns which is I want. its messy i know, but i want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Approach #3:

I am not sure why you are getting Memory Error. Let me try an alternate approach. I converted the dataset into a normal dictionary that can be loaded into pandas as a normal dataframe. See if this works.

```
d = {}
for i in data:
    for k,v in i.items():
        if k in d:
            d[k] = list(d[k]) + v.split(',')
        else:
            d[k] = v.split(',')

m = max(len(v) for k,v in d.items())
dd = {k:v+['']*(m-len(v)) for k,v in d.items()}

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dd)
print (df)
```

## Approach #2:

Can you try this option instead:

```
data = [{k:v.split(',') for k,v in i.items()} for i in data]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
dc = df.columns.to_list()
for col in dc:
    df = df.explode(col)
print (df)
```

## Approach #1:

You can do the following:

```
data = [
    {"var1": "EEA", "var2": "%K12%"},
    {"var1": "OVERALL"},
    {"var1": "ETLA"},
    {"var1": "A,B,C,D,E"},
    {"var1": "M,Q"},
    {"var1": "G,H"},
    {"var1": "I,J"},
    {"var1": "K,L,M"},
    {"var3": "R,T", "var2": "F"},
    {"var3": "EDUCATION", "var4": "TM"},
    {"var3": "A,B", "var4": "TM", "var5": "CCE,CCT,PP"},
    {"var1": "PHLT,PPSK,PLES,LPES", "var4": "HI"},
    {"var3": "EDUCATION", "var4": "HI", "var5": "CCM"},
    {"var3": "EDUCATION", "var4": "HI", "var5": "PP"},
    {"var4": "HI", "var5": "CCM"},
    {"var4": "HI", "var5": "PP"},
    {"var3": "A,B", "var6": "C"},
    {"var3": "", "var1": "", "var4": "", "var2": "", "var5": "", "var6": ""},
]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
dc = df.columns.to_list()
for col in dc:
    df[col] = df[col].str.split(',')
    df = df.explode(col)
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
       var1   var2       var3 var4 var5 var6
0       EEA  %K12%        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   OVERALL    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2      ETLA    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3         A    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3         B    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3         C    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3         D    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3         E    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4         M    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4         Q    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5         G    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5         H    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6         I    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6         J    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7         K    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7         L    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7         M    NaN        NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8       NaN      F          R  NaN  NaN  NaN
8       NaN      F          T  NaN  NaN  NaN
9       NaN    NaN  EDUCATION   TM  NaN  NaN
10      NaN    NaN          A   TM  CCE  NaN
10      NaN    NaN          A   TM  CCT  NaN
10      NaN    NaN          A   TM   PP  NaN
10      NaN    NaN          B   TM  CCE  NaN
10      NaN    NaN          B   TM  CCT  NaN
10      NaN    NaN          B   TM   PP  NaN
11     PHLT    NaN        NaN   HI  NaN  NaN
11     PPSK    NaN        NaN   HI  NaN  NaN
11     PLES    NaN        NaN   HI  NaN  NaN
11     LPES    NaN        NaN   HI  NaN  NaN
12      NaN    NaN  EDUCATION   HI  CCM  NaN
13      NaN    NaN  EDUCATION   HI   PP  NaN
14      NaN    NaN        NaN   HI  CCM  NaN
15      NaN    NaN        NaN   HI   PP  NaN
16      NaN    NaN          A  NaN  NaN    C
16      NaN    NaN          B  NaN  NaN    C
17
```

Comment: got MemoryError:

Comment: just now i have ran

Comment: Try the new approach i just posted.

Comment: can you help me writing df.assign,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177914/why-use-pandas-assign-rather-than-simply-initialize-new-column   `df.assign(var1=df['var1'].str.split(',')).explode('var1')` this is for one column, how to apply on columns

Comment: Try the new approach.

Comment: see if this post will help you resolve memory errors ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283220/memory-error-in-python/37726090#37726090

Comment: perfectly working what is dd = {k:v+['']*(m-len(v)) for k,v in d.items()}

Answer (score 0):

```
df=[
{"var1": "EEA", "var2": "%K12%"},
{"var1": "OVERALL"},
{"var1": "ETLA"},
{"var1": "A,B,C,D,E"},
{"var1": "M,Q"},
{"var1": "G,H"},
{"var1": "I,J"},
{"var1": "K,L,M"},
{"var3": "R,T", "var2": "F"},
{"var3": "EDUCATION", "var4": "TM"},
{"var3": "A,B", "var4": "TM", "var5": "CCE,CCT,PP"},
{"var1": "PHLT,PPSK,PLES,LPES", "var4": "HI"},
{"var3": "EDUCATION", "var4": "HI", "var5": "CCM"},
{"var3": "EDUCATION", "var4": "HI", "var5": "PP"},
{"var4": "HI", "var5": "CCM"},
{"var4": "HI", "var5": "PP"},
{"var3": "A,B", "var6": "C"},
{"var3": "", "var1": "", "var4": "", "var2": "", "var5": "", "var6": ""},
]
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
df=df.applymap(lambda value:value.split(',') if str(value)!='nan' else [])
for col in df.columns:
   df=df.explode(col)
```

This code block explodes every column

[image]