# Pandas inconsistent speed and memory usage when manipulating data frames on Windows

Tags: python, pandas, windows

I am using pandas on Windows 10 and run into some inconsistent performance issues. The data sets I am working with are not small, but not huge either, perhaps of the order of 1GB.

I generally use code of the form.

```
df = pd.read_csv('...')
new_column = df.column_a / df.column_b
df = df.assign(new_column=new_column)
```

What I observe is that the speed and memory usage varies significantly from run to run.
Most of the time it should be <2GB and the calculation above runs smoothly. I use Atom's Hydrogen Plugin for interactive execution.

Every now and then, after several executions, things suddenly grind almost to a halt. Windows task manager reports memory usage of the Python session of over 6GB. But it is not repeatable. When I restart and walk through the code, this might happen at a different point, or not at all.

Any ideas what causes this and how I could avoid it? I am not sure whether the system tries to allocate memory for temporary results and squeezes the ram, or whether it is some interaction between Hydrogen and Pandas, or something completely different. If this were to happen at a merge, it would be more intuitive, as there is a potential for frames balooning, but this here happens on operations on 1d-numpy arrays.

I tried pandas modin, but ran into a lot of Windows issues. Unfortunately, the work requires me to use Windows so switching to Unix is not an option.

I would be appreciate any help.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177914/why-use-pandas-assign-rather-than-simply-initialize-new-column. It's good discussion on what assign does vs directly adding a new column to the dataframe. Essentially you are making a copy of a large dataframe. Maybe unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks, that might be it. It still does not quite explain why it happens only some of the time, but it is a good start to make my code a bit better.