# ValueError: The truth value of a series is ambiguous. Creating new series in DataFrame with np.where

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe based on two conditional statements. If both conditions are satisfied, the new column should mimic the stock['return'] column. If they are not satisfied, the new column should have a 0. Please help.

stock['strat1_return'] = np.where((stock['close'] < stock['2_dayma'] and stock['close'] < stock['5_dayma']), [stock['return'], np.nan])

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use `where` when creating a new column based on other ones.

The [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) method is more appropriate.

Here's a quick example from the docs:

```py
>>> df.assign(temp_f=df['temp_c'] * 9 / 5 + 32)
>>>          temp_c  temp_f
>>> Portland    17.0    62.6
>>> Berkeley    25.0    77.0
```

In your example you first need to create a pandas function that will go through each cell. because your code is trying to read the entire columns each time, hence the error.

So, in your case this snippet should do the trick:

```py
strat1_return = stock.apply(
    lambda x: x['return'] if x['close'] < x['2_dayma'] and x['close'] < x['5_dayma'] else np.nan)
)
stock = stock.assign(strat1_return=strat1_return.values)
```

Or without `assign`:

```py
stock['strat1_return'] = stock.apply(
    lambda x: x['return'] if x['close'] < x['2_dayma'] and x['close'] < x['5_dayma'] else np.nan)
)
```

The difference between using `apply` or `assign` for creating a new column can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178021/7456788)