# Apart from 'assign', is there any other pandas method we can use for creating/changing columns?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am a pandas user and I am used to method chaining with pandas functions because I think the readability is better. Among the functions pandas provided, [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) takes an important role when I am creating or changing columns of a dataframe.

Recently, I would like to know the performance of the `assign` function comparing with normal assignment method. For example,

normal assignment method:

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'col0': [1, 2, 3], 'col1': ['i', 'j', 'k']})
a['col2'] = [7, 8, 9]
```

`assign` function:

```
b = pd.DataFrame({'col0': [1, 2, 3], 'col1': ['i', 'j', 'k']})
b = b.assign(col2 = [7, 8, 9])
```

The 2 ways give the same output. However, when I look at their identity with `id()`, it suggests that the `assign` method actually gives a new object rather than mutating the original object `b`. For example,

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'col0': [1, 2, 3], 'col1': ['i', 'j', 'k']})
a_id_old = id(a)
a['col2'] = [7, 8, 9]
a_id_new = id(a)

b = pd.DataFrame({'col0': [1, 2, 3], 'col1': ['i', 'j', 'k']})
b_id_old = id(b)
b = b.assign(col2 = [7, 8, 9])
b_id_new = id(b)

print('For a, old id: {} and new id: {}'.format(a_id_old , a_id_new))
print('For b, old id: {} and new id: {}'.format(b_id_old , b_id_new))
```

I found that it will gives a distinct object if we use the `assign` method. The official document had also suggests this method will return a new object. Similar things have been discussed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177914/why-use-pandas-assign-rather-than-simply-initialize-new-column).

I have 2 questions for this:

1. As the `assign` method will output a new object, does it necessarily mean that it will be slower than the normal assignment method?
2. Is there any other method that can enable me to create/change columns with a method chaining style?

I notice that the pandas core team members encouraged us to use the method chaining style (reference [here](https://youtu.be/hK6o_TDXXN8?t=410) and [here](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining.html)). However, the 'performance issue' of the `assign` now confuses me to use it or not.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the experiment:

```
import time

a = pd.DataFrame({'col0': [1, 2, 3], 'col1': ['i', 'j', 'k']})
s = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    a['col2'] = [7, 8, 9]
e = time.time()
print('Simaple:', e-s)

b = pd.DataFrame({'col0': [1, 2, 3], 'col1': ['i', 'j', 'k']})
s = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    b = b.assign(col2 = [7, 8, 9])
e = time.time()
print('Using assign:', e-s)
```

The output:

```
Simaple: 7.7636802196502686
Using assign: 34.687790870666504
```

Comment: Thanks for the experiment! I can see quite a large difference in terms of performance. So what if I would like to stick with method chaining programming without loss of performance? Is there an alternative?

Comment: As much as I know there is not another method.